# How to create a Toolbar below the Navigation bar in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How to create a Toolbar below the Navigation bar in SwiftUI, as shown in the picture? Thank you!

[image]

Here is the code I'm using for the Navigation bar:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.yellow
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
                    Button {
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "globe")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create your own:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                
                Color.yellow
                
                // Your 2. toolbar
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button { } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button { } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "2.circle")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button { } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "3.circle")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding()

            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
                    Button {
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "globe")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```